# css is not working when declare inline

Tags: html, css

This is my html and css

```
<html>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .rtop *, .rbottom *{
      display:block;
      height:1px;                  
      overflow:hidden;
    }
  </style>
 <link rel='StyleSheet' href='roundedCorner.css' type='text/css'>
 <body>

   <div id='abhishek1'>
     <div style='width:200px;height:5px;'>    
       <b class='rtop' >
         <b class='r1_top' style='background-color:#6e99d4 '> </b> </br>  
         <b class='r2_top' style='background-color:#6e99d4'> </b>  </br>
         <b class='r3_top' style='background-color:#6e99d4'> </b>  </br>
         <b class='r4_top' style='background-color:#6e99d4'> </b>  </br>
       </b></br>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If i remove `display:block` from `.rtop` and put as inline style it's not producing the same result but I don't know why.

Comment: "display:block" is not applied on rtop but in its children, have you put it on rX_top elements ?

Comment: Show the codes you have actually used and describe what happens (insteads of mere “not producing the same result”, which could mean almost anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because most likely, u put it in the wrong element or forgot to close something  with semicolon.
Note that in the head it does not apply to rtop and rbottom, but to their child elements so u gotta put it in every one of the  r1_ r2_ etc. Elements.

Comment: tahn you for the answer it's working .Cant upvote because of less reputation

Comment: you are most welcome. please accept my answer by clicking the green V under the votes indicator. :)

Answer (score 0):

The style is applied to `.rtop *`, not `.rtop`, so to apply it inline you would need to apply it to all child elements:

```
<html>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .rtop *{
      height:1px;                  
      overflow:hidden;
    }
    .rbottom * {
      display:block;
      height:1px;                  
      overflow:hidden;
    }
  </style>
 <link rel='StyleSheet' href='roundedCorner.css' type='text/css'>
 <body>

   <div id='abhishek1'>
     <div style='width:200px;height:5px;'>    
       <b class='rtop' >
         <b class='r1_top' style='display: block; background-color:#6e99d4'> </b> <br style='display: block;'>  
         <b class='r2_top' style='display: block; background-color:#6e99d4'> </b> <br style='display: block;'>
         <b class='r3_top' style='display: block; background-color:#6e99d4'> </b> <br style='display: block;'>
         <b class='r4_top' style='display: block; background-color:#6e99d4'> </b> <br style='display: block;'>
       </b></br>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```